# Dynamic Variable Initialization Error in Java

Tags: java

I have this piece of code which is giving an error saying

> variable priorityCheck is not initialized

The output that I require is that the query executes with the given value of `priorityCheck` in a loop. Here is the code:

```
String query;
String StrComp;
int PerFound;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String priorityCheck;

// running the queries
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
  StrComp = types.get(i).toString();
  PerFound = StrComp.indexOf("%");
  if (StrComp.indexOf("P1") != -1) {
    priorityCheck =
        "a.SubscriptionType=0 and a.applyticketpriorityfilterflag = 1 and a.P1 & a.P2 = 1";
  } else if (StrComp.indexOf("P2") != -1) {
    priorityCheck =
        "a.SubscriptionType=0 and a.applyticketpriorityfilterflag = 1 and a.P3 & a.P4 = 1";
  } else if (StrComp.indexOf("WO") != -1) {
    priorityCheck = "a.SubscriptionType=2";
  }

  if (PerFound == -1) {

    query =
        "SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,a.LastStatusDate,GETUTCDATE()) FROM SASubscriptionPIIView a,SAWorkflowToolPIIView b WHERE (a.toolid=b.id and a.active=1 and a.SubscriptionCategory=0 and "
            + priorityCheck
            + " and b.toolname like "
            + types.get(i)
            + ")";
    writeLog(query);
  } else {
    query =
        "SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,a.LastStatusDate,GETUTCDATE()) FROM SASubscriptionPIIView a,SAWorkflowToolPIIView b WHERE (a.toolid=b.id and a.active=1 and a.SubscriptionCategory=0 and "
            + priorityCheck
            + " and b.toolname like "
            + types.get(i)
            + ")";
    writeLog(query);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code and please format it

Comment: What if `names.size()==0`? What is the value assigned to `priorityCheck` then?

Comment: if `StrComp` was not `P1` or `P2` or `WO` then what do you think `priorityCheck` would be.  You know it is OK, but the compiler doesn't.  So set `String priorityCheck = "SOMEVALUE";`

Comment: `String priorityCheck;` is not initialized, and you are using it but there is a possibility that the code never initialize it. Meaning that this can't compile

Comment: Did You Know About Variable Scope?

Comment: Also: don't hand-roll SQL queries. Use a `PreparedStatement`. See http://bobby-tables.com.

Comment: @AndyTurner That is never the case as it takes that value from a config file which already has data. I am only concerned about priorityCheck here. When I had just one value for that it was working fine. Now that i have two more values it is giving me initialization error.

Comment: Please rewrite this as a [mcve], properly indented, and following Java naming conventions.

Comment: @Aarthi maybe, but the compiler cannot know that. It takes the pessimistic assessment, and assumes the loop may never be run.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think if one were to format the code, it would be possible to see that **all** of the code is within the `for` loop

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes, I spotted that subsequently. I was a bit too far underground to reply though.

Comment: Unrelated: you want to read about java naming conventions. Variable names go camelCase. And being **inconsistent** about casing as you do makes things even worse. Then: you expect us to spend our time to help you. So you please spend the 3 minutes it takes to properly **indent** all of your code. Form matters; bugs hide in unreadable code. And what you are posting here is one ugly, unreadable mess.

Comment: @AarthiMuthusami I have fixed the indentation, which makes things an awful lot clearer. Indentation is so important to convey the structure of the code; you should get into the habit of formatting the code in your IDE (or just learn to do it manually, it's not especially hard, and pays dividends in terms of readability).

Comment: Any further comments on the answers ... are they helpful? Is something missing in order to make one of them "accept" worthy?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please initialize variable `priorityCheck` with some default value - `""`, for example.
The problem is that in code

```
if (StrComp.indexOf("P1")!=-1)
{
            priorityCheck="a.SubscriptionType=0 and a.applyticketpriorityfilterflag = 1 and a.P1 & a.P2 = 1";
}

else if (StrComp.indexOf("P2")!=-1)
{
            priorityCheck="a.SubscriptionType=0 and a.applyticketpriorityfilterflag = 1 and a.P3 & a.P4 = 1";
}
else if (StrComp.indexOf("WO")!=-1)
{
            priorityCheck="a.SubscriptionType=2";
}
```

variable `priorityCheck` can be not initialized - else statement is missing.

Comment: @mic_0406 is there a better way to have this loop?

Comment: I dont see the whole for loop, that that posted is fine. You just need to initialize `priorityCheck` with `null`, `""` or some default string to fix compiler error

Answer (score 1):

This error basically means: you are using (reading!) a variable in your code, but there are paths in your code that do **not** initialize your variable.

Simplified:

```
String foo;
if (whatever) {
  foo = "from if";
}

bar = foo;
```

That is what your code is doing: it contains a way to reach a "read" for `priorityCheck` without a previous "write" to that variable. One simple fix:

```
String foo = "not initialized";
```

In other words: think what the variable should contain as "default". Or make sure that there are **no** paths without assigning a value.

Beyond that: your **real** problem is that you are writing overly complicated code. If you really intend to write "database code" at this point; consider reading a bit about "clean coding practices"; for example the [Single Layer of Abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction) principle. Your problem is that you are writing code that is so complex that you can't see any more what the code is doing.

Comment: Nice and simple

Comment: `""` might be a better initializer, as it will make the SQL query definitely invalid. Or, `else { throw new SomeKindOfException(); }`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I used that string on purpose to create awareness.